# Android Facebook - How to get like count for a post?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am searching for this for about 2 weeks but cannot find anything. Every response about that refers to an older version of Facebook API. I can get feed of a facebook page, but I want to get like and comment counts for those posts too. I am playing with Graph Explorer but can not find any solution.

I really appreciate if anyone knows it and shares with me.

Thank you in advance!

Here my GET request:

```
      GraphRequest g = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            url,
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                   // my code

                }
            }
      );

      Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
      parameters.putString("fields", "full_picture,message,type,source,created_time,id");
      parameters.putString("limit","50");
      g.setParameters(parameters);
      g.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have had a look on the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments

A sample call would be

```
GET /BuzzFeed/posts?limit=1&fields=id,message,full_picture,type,source,created_time,comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true).limit(0)
```

which fetches the most recent `BuzzFeed` post from the page and gets the details you want:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "21898300328_10153915728380329",
      "message": "",
      "full_picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtl1/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/11951871_10153915728380329_7635044619009730855_n.jpg?oh=bcb1e2cb663815c83219edff892a9741&oe=566396B1",
      "type": "photo",
      "created_time": "2015-09-02T06:32:00+0000",
      "likes": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 4263,
          "can_like": true,
          "has_liked": false
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "order": "ranked",
          "total_count": 172,
          "can_comment": true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/21898300328/posts?fields=id,message,full_picture,type,source,created_time,comments.summary%28true%29.limit%280%29,likes.summary%28true%29.limit%280%29&limit=1&format=json&since=1441175520&access_token=&__paging_token=&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/21898300328/posts?fields=id,message,full_picture,type,source,created_time,comments.summary%28true%29.limit%280%29,likes.summary%28true%29.limit%280%29&limit=1&format=json&access_token=&until=1441175520&__paging_token="
  }
}
```

So, in Adroid code this would equivalent

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
      parameters.putString("fields", "id,message,full_picture,type,source,created_time,comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true).limit(0)");
      parameters.putString("limit","50");
      g.setParameters(parameters);
      g.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I read these documents but didn't get I can do something like likes.summary(true).

Comment: Now I am trying to get "Comments" by using Graph api and this time I am reading whole document about "{post_id}/comments" but cannot get right response. Can you edit your answer and help for that too? Sorry for my noobish programming skills. The page I am using is : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/comments