# Facebook Android SDK - Get a public post detais doesn't show full fields

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook SDK to my android app. 
I followed guide : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post . I try to get detail a post in a public group by method:

```
final String POST_ID = "1446400445645839_1796360410649839";
new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/" + POST_ID,
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                 /* handle the result */
                Log.d("DEBUG","post detail ---------------------");
                Log.d("DEBUG",response.toString());
                Log.d("DEBUG","post detail--------------------------");
            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

And I got the response:

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject:
>   {"created_time":"2016-09-25T02:57:29+0000","message":"Because of
>   its_________for outstanding customer service, Mei’s Hair Salon is the
>   most popular business of its kind in the area. \nA. approval\nB.
>   estimation\nC. probability\nD. reputation\nCâu này trong ETS 2016. đáp
>   án theo sách mình down là D. Bạn nào giải thích giúp mình giữa C và D
>   được không ạ?","id":"1446400445645839_1796360410649839"}, error: null}

Check out facebook fields table below:
[image]

It seems that some fields are missed such as name,caption, from...
Could you explain and give me suggestion to get fields like name, caption, from ?

UPDATE :
I found the solution for this post at: [Android Facebook - How to get like count for a post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335120/android-facebook-how-to-get-like-count-for-a-post/32346664#32346664).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

> By default, not all fields in a node or edge are returned when you
>   make a query. You can choose the fields or edges that you want
>   returned with the fields query parameter. This is really useful for
>   making your API calls more efficient and fast.
>
> For example, the following Graph API call
>   https://graph.facebook.com/bgolub?fields=id,name,picture will only
>   return the id, name, and picture in Ben's profile:

Comment: Thank you. I tried . But I got the same response. Do you have any suggestion ? final String POST_ID = "1446400445645839_1796360410649839";
GraphRequest request =new GraphRequest(....
);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
}